# TextView can't wrap arround text in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android

I've got an issue with TextView in ConstraintLayout, the xml with constraints looks like this:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/section_title"
    tools:text="Data Processing, Hosting, and Related Services"
    />
```

The whole TextView is styled and in style I'm using flag `android:breakStrategy="balanced"` so the TextView presents like this:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see it's expanding it's width to fill the constraint and doesn't wrap around the text so the background doesn't display correctly. Anyone knows the solution?

Comment: what happens when you dont use this tag android:breakStrategy="balanced" ?

Comment: It's moving only "Services" to next line, also leaves a bit of empty space at the end of first line, it looks just bad

Answer (score 1):

**Remove** this tag `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`

**Reason** -

> you have given constraint to textview which will align itself to end
> of parent, so app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" is enough
> to align it to start of parent and it will wrap content as a
> background

**Example**

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/section_title"
    tools:text="Data Processing, Hosting,\nand Related Services"
    />
```

Comment: It fixed issue with wrapping, but because of lack of end constraint it doesn't respect the end margin now

Comment: please post a picture of now so I can see the issue

Comment: also post a picture of your required design so I can help with that